# If using javascript convert /n to >

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have a piece of text that comes from the backend with /n string in it, but I hope I can replace this with
a lot of ways I found on the Internet, but I still can't replace it with a label smoothly, does anyone know the reason Caused?

Thanks for your help.

```js
let demo = document.querySelector('.demo').textContent;
console.log(demo)
demo.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');
```

```html
<p class="demo">尚有 1 個職缺使用母公司的點數，\n關閉後才可解除綁定</p>
```

Comment: So is there any other way without using new RegExp?

Comment: `demo.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');` returns a new value which you do nothing with. it does not do an in-place replace of the string - and even if it did, that would not effect `document.querySelector('.demo').textContent` - it would (but does not) effect `demo`

Comment: also, why the `\r?`? the string in the element has `\n` literally ... a backslash and an n ... it's not a newline character in that  element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const demoEl = document.querySelector('.demo')
demoEl.innerHTML = demoEl.textContent.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');
```

```html
<p class="demo">尚有 1 個職缺使用母公司的點數，\n關閉後才可解除綁定</p>
```

A couple of points:

1. Your text doesn't include a new line character so you need to match for the character combination of `\n` like so... `/\\n/g`
2. Your just replacing the content reference, you need to apply the replace to the elements innerHTML